# How to implement static/fixed SQLGroupInfo without table on ProFTPD?

Tags: proftpd

I've found some tutorials for `ProFTP` with `MySQL` connection. But these handling by general scheme, 99% of them are identically. And do not go into the detail of the configuration.

Is `SQLGroupInfo` required?

I've noticed the groups are always the same. Therefore, only one database record is needed in the groups table.

I want to fix this by omitting the group table and setting it directly in the configuration.

How can I do this?

The first try was, to register a custom query:

```
# Hardcoded groups
SQLNamedQuery get-groups SELECT 'ftp' AS `name`, 2001 AS `group`, 'ftpd' AS `members`
SQLGroupInfo sql:/get-groups
```

But here, i've get following error:

> fatal: SQLGroupInfo: badly formatted parameter on line 34 of '/etc/proftpd/sql.conf'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, i must return correct rows like `gid`, `groupname` and `members`. If wanted, you can remove the `FROM $table WHERE [...]`, thats not required.

Here is the solution:

```
# Hardcoded groups
SQLNamedQuery get-group-by-name SELECT "`username` AS `groupname`, '1010' AS `gid`, `username` AS `members` FROM `fh_ftp_user` WHERE `username`='%{0}'"
SQLNamedQuery get-group-by-id SELECT "`username` AS `groupname`, '1010' AS `gid`, `username` AS `members` FROM `fh_ftp_user` WHERE `username`='%{0}'"
SQLNamedQuery get-group-by-member SELECT "`username` AS `groupname`, '1010' AS `gid`, `username` AS `members` FROM `fh_ftp_user` WHERE `username`='%{0}'"
SQLGroupInfo custom:/get-group-by-name/get-group-by-id/get-group-by-member
```

Or

```
# Hardcoded groups
SQLNamedQuery get-hardcoded-group SELECT "'YourHardcodedGroup' AS `groupname`, 1010 AS `gid`, 'MemberName' AS `members`"
SQLGroupInfo custom:/get-hardcoded-group
```